# CSS line-height rules being ignored

Tags: php, html, css

I can't figure out how to change my dynamic table's line height with CSS when printing. Even when using the line-height property it is ignored. Below is a screenshot. Any suggestions? I have

[screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5LBf.png)

EDIT: Thank you all for the welcome message and suggestions,

here is my current CSS (Sorry for it being messy)

```
/*Remove footer*/
.footer .footer-credits {
    display: none;
}

.products{
    text-align:center;
}

#primary{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.page-title-section{
    display:none;
}

.page-title{
    padding-bottom:40px;
}

p{
    color:black;
}

form, label{
    width:100%
}


.contact_form_right_new{
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.form_dist{
    margin:0 auto;
}

.wpf-center, #wpforms-2270-field_0, #wpforms-2270-field_1, #wpforms-2270-field_4{
     margin-left: auto !important;
     margin-right: auto !important;
     max-width: 500px; 
}

.wpf-center .wpforms-head-container, 
.wpf-center .wpforms-submit-container {
     text-align: center; 
}
.wpf-center, #wpforms-2323-field_0, #wpforms-2323-field_0-last, #wpforms-2323-field_1, #wpforms-2323-field_4{
     margin-left: auto !important;
     margin-right: auto !important;
     max-width: 500px; 
}

label{
    color:black
}

.g-recaptcha{
    text-align:center;
}

#wpforms-submit-2270{
    color:white;
    background-color:#2b75ff;
}

#wpforms-submit-2323{
    color:white;
    background-color:#2b75ff;
}
@media print{
    @page {
        size: landscape;
        margin: 20px;
    }

}
@media print {
    .content-area.pt0{
        padding-top:0
    } 
    .site-header {
        display: none;
    }
    .footer-callout{
        display:none;
    }
    footer{
        display:none;
    }

    #results td{
    padding:0;
        font-size:8px;
    }


    table {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
}

}

.aimix-title{
    color:white;
    text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #000,
                  2px 2px 0 #000,
                 1px -1px 0 #000;
}

#pgc-65-0-1{
    margin-left:70px;
}






@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .footer-widget-area .footer-widget:first-child {
    width: 66.6%;
}
.footer-widget-area .footer-widget:nth-child(2) {
    width: 33.3%;
}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {


    #wpcw_contact-3{
        text-align:center;
        margin-top:15%
    }

}

#wpcf7-f2383-p51-o1{
    text-align:left
}
```

EDIT: here is the code for the table (I am fully aware I could have just used a class for styling th and td)

```
 <table id = "results" style="-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; color: black; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;">
           <tr>
               <th style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
                   Product
               </th>
               <th style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
                   Description
               </th>
               <th style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
                   Usage
               </th>
               <th style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
                   First Aid Directions
               </th>
               <th style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
                   Symbol
               </th>
           </tr>
                <?php foreach($productID as $id) {
                    $product = get_product($id);
                        ?>

                        <?php ?>
                            <tr style="background-color:<?php echo (get_attribute('colour',$product)); ?> !important;">
                                <td style="padding:6px; border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $product -> get_name(); ?></td>
                                <td style="padding:6px; border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $product -> get_description(); ?></td>
                                <td style="padding:6px; border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo(get_attribute('uses-and-methods',$product)); ?></td>
                                <td style="padding:6px; border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo (get_attribute('first-aid-directions',$product)); ?></td>
                                <td style="padding:6px; width:80px; border: 1px solid black;"><img id="ghs" src="<?php echo get_ghs('ghs',$product)?>" style="height:auto; width:auto;"/></td>


                           </tr>

                        <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with **clearly** stating what your desired result is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your table looks good for me

Comment: I want to get rid of the large spacing between the lines to fit more rows per page

Comment: Can you add your html for just the table?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ put your html and css and ASK experts, they will help you!

Comment: @JasonB I have just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ryan,
This answer is kind of a "non-answer" answer. Here is a CodePen with the code you posted and some filler text, as well as a snippet.

https://codepen.io/Jason_B/pen/zeYKGJ

I don't see the big spacing that you show in the screenshot. Try the print view of the codepen for verification. I hope this non-answer is helpful to you in a few ways. The code you shared has no issues, here are some suggested debugging steps, and don't be surprised if the question gets closed, it wasn't asked following the SO guidelines.

- You should show us your generated HTML, not the PHP. Perhaps you have line height hardcoded in the contents of the database or the product object.
- What browser is this happening in. All of them? If it is only one, you may have an extension causing this. If it is every browser, you know it is your code, and you also know that the code causing the problem is not the code you shared.
- If the problem is not in the code you shared, try using an html validator on your generated code. An unclosed tag prior to this table could be leaking styles like line height into the rest of the page.
- Limit the code that is being rendered on your end until you have just the table html and the table related styles, which will include things that you don't have here - the td contents and font-face for certain, and we'll take another look. I'm pretty sure that if you've gotten this far and followed the debugging plan you'll already have it licked!

```css
/*Remove footer*/

.footer .footer-credits {
  display: none;
}

.products {
  text-align: center;
}

#primary {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.page-title-section {
  display: none;
}

.page-title {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

p {
  color: black;
}

form,
label {
  width: 100%
}

.contact_form_right_new {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form_dist {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wpf-center,
#wpforms-2270-field_0,
#wpforms-2270-field_1,
#wpforms-2270-field_4 {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.wpf-center .wpforms-head-container,
.wpf-center .wpforms-submit-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.wpf-center,
#wpforms-2323-field_0,
#wpforms-2323-field_0-last,
#wpforms-2323-field_1,
#wpforms-2323-field_4 {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  max-width: 500px;
}

label {
  color: black
}

.g-recaptcha {
  text-align: center;
}

#wpforms-submit-2270 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #2b75ff;
}

#wpforms-submit-2323 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #2b75ff;
}

@media print {
  @page {
    size: landscape;
    margin: 20px;
  }
}

@media print {
  .content-area.pt0 {
    padding-top: 0
  }
  .site-header {
    display: none;
  }
  .footer-callout {
    display: none;
  }
  footer {
    display: none;
  }
  #results td {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 8px;
  }
  table {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
  }
}

.aimix-title {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #000, 2px 2px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000;
}

#pgc-65-0-1 {
  margin-left: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .footer-widget-area .footer-widget:first-child {
    width: 66.6%;
  }
  .footer-widget-area .footer-widget:nth-child(2) {
    width: 33.3%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #wpcw_contact-3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15%
  }
}

#wpcf7-f2383-p51-o1 {
  text-align: left
}
```

```html
<table id="results" style="-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; color: black; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <th style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
      Product
    </th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
      Description
    </th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
      Usage
    </th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
      First Aid Directions
    </th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
      Symbol
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr style="background-color:green">
    <td style="padding:6px; border: 1px solid black;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et consequat magna. Nunc pulvinar dolor fermentum scelerisque congue. Donec et felis eget ex laoreet dictum. Mauris at maximus erat. Ut dapibus est eu urna congue, id varius leo condimentum.
      Vivamus et ultrices felis. Proin condimentum mauris id risus tincidunt egestas sit amet nec nulla. Sed risus purus, tempor eget venenatis id, egestas at magna.
    </td>
    <td style="padding:6px; border: 1px solid black;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et consequat magna. Nunc pulvinar dolor fermentum scelerisque congue. Donec et felis eget ex laoreet dictum. Mauris at maximus erat. Ut dapibus est eu urna congue, id varius leo condimentum.
      Vivamus et ultrices felis. Proin condimentum mauris id risus tincidunt egestas sit amet nec nulla. Sed risus purus, tempor eget venenatis id, egestas at magna.
    </td>
    <td style="padding:6px; border: 1px solid black;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et consequat magna. Nunc pulvinar dolor fermentum scelerisque congue. Donec et felis eget ex laoreet dictum. Mauris at maximus erat. Ut dapibus est eu urna congue, id varius leo condimentum.
      Vivamus et ultrices felis. Proin condimentum mauris id risus tincidunt egestas sit amet nec nulla. Sed risus purus, tempor eget venenatis id, egestas at magna.
    </td>
    <td style="padding:6px; border: 1px solid black;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et consequat magna. Nunc pulvinar dolor fermentum scelerisque congue. Donec et felis eget ex laoreet dictum. Mauris at maximus erat. Ut dapibus est eu urna congue, id varius leo condimentum.
      Vivamus et ultrices felis. Proin condimentum mauris id risus tincidunt egestas sit amet nec nulla. Sed risus purus, tempor eget venenatis id, egestas at magna.
    </td>
    <td style="padding:6px; width:80px; border: 1px solid black;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et consequat magna. Nunc pulvinar dolor fermentum scelerisque congue. Donec et felis eget ex laoreet dictum. Mauris at maximus erat. Ut dapibus est eu urna congue, id varius leo condimentum.
      Vivamus et ultrices felis. Proin condimentum mauris id risus tincidunt egestas sit amet nec nulla. Sed risus purus, tempor eget venenatis id, egestas at magna.
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```